# Spare autoencoders in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, autoencoder

Is there an example of sparse autoencoders in tensorflow? I was to able to run and understand the normal one from here https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/autoencoder.py

For sparse, do I just need to modify the cost function?

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import scipy.fftpack
import pdb, random
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from read_audio import read_audio


start,end= 3050,5723
#start=end=None
audio_data=read_audio("LDC93S1",start,end)

def overlapping_chunks(l, sub_array_size, overlap_size):
    return [l[i:i+sub_array_size] for i in range(0, len(l)-overlap_size, overlap_size)]

def conv_frq_domain(signal):
    fft_abs=abs(scipy.fft(signal))
    fft_sorted=np.sort(fft_abs)[::-1]
    top_100=fft_sorted[:100]
    return top_100


sample_len=100
samples=overlapping_chunks(audio_data,sample_len,50)
freq_samples=[]
for sample in samples:
    freq_samples.append(conv_frq_domain(sample))

examples=samples
print("Number of samples", str(len(examples)))
#pdb.set_trace()

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 2000
batch_size = 2
display_step = 100

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 1000 # 1st layer num features
n_hidden_2 = 650 # 2nd layer num features
n_input = sample_len

# tf Graph input (only pictures)
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])

weights = {
    'encoder_h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'encoder_h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'decoder_h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_input])),
}
biases = {
    'encoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'encoder_b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'decoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input])),
}

# Building the encoder
def encoder(x):
    # Encoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #1
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['encoder_h1']),
                                   biases['encoder_b1']))
    # Decoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #2
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['encoder_h2']),
                                   biases['encoder_b2']))
    return layer_1,layer_2


# Building the decoder
def decoder(x):
    # Encoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #1
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['decoder_h1']),
                                   biases['decoder_b1']))
    # Decoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #2
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['decoder_h2']),
                                   biases['decoder_b2'])
    return layer_2

def kl_divergence(p_1, p_hat):
    num_len=p_1.get_shape()[0]
    term1 = p_1 * tf.log(p_1)
    term2 = p_1 * tf.log(p_hat)
    term3 = tf.sub(tf.ones(num_len),p_1) * tf.log(tf.sub(tf.ones(num_len),p_1))
    term4 = tf.sub(tf.ones(num_len),p_1) * tf.log(tf.sub(tf.ones(num_len) ,p_hat))
    return tf.sub(tf.add(term1,term3),tf.add(term2,term4))

def sparsity_penalty(hidden_layer_acts, sparsity_level=0.05, sparse_reg=1e-3, batch_size=-1):
    # = T.extra_ops.repeat(sparsity_level, self.nhid)
    sparsity_level_vec=tf.ones(hidden_layer_acts.get_shape()[1])*sparsity_level
    sparsity_penalty = 0
    avg_act = Mean = tf.reduce_mean(hidden_layer_acts,1)
    kl_div = kl_divergence(sparsity_level_vec, avg_act)
    sparsity_penalty = sparse_reg * tf.reduce_sum(kl_div,0)
    return sparsity_penalty

# Construct model
encoder_op1, encoder_op2 = encoder(X)
decoder_op = decoder(encoder_op2)

# Prediction
y_pred = decoder_op
# Targets (Labels) are the input data.
y_true = X

# Define loss and optimizer, minimize the squared error
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y_true - y_pred, 2)+sparsity_penalty(encoder_op2))
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
train_data=examples

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    total_batch = int(len(examples)/batch_size)
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        #random.shuffle(train_data)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs=train_data[i:i+2]
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: batch_xs})
        if epoch ==2500:
            pdb.set_trace()
            encode_decode = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={X: batch_xs})
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1),"cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

Comment: Yes, just add the sparsity penalty to cost, ie the KL term from here http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Autoencoders_and_Sparsity

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I iterate over the hidden units to add it?

Comment: That's the next exercise in that class -- you end up with implementation that has no loops and can be plugged into matlab/theano/tensorflow -- http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Exercise:Vectorization

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm trying to figure out how to modify the cost function from the same example, and am having issues.